# Regex to get 2 specific characters between other 2 specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string:

`[](first-(second))`

I would like to remove `(` and `)` between `[](...` and last `...)`

With that being said, I'm currently using `(?<=\[\]\()(.*?)(?=\))`

I assume `(.*?)` needs to be replaced with some sort of expression that will find `(` and `)` in between.

Something similar to `string.replace(/(?<=\[\]\()(.*?)(?=\))/g, '')`

And the string should look like `[](first-second)`

Comment: Try greedy one, `(?<=\[\]\()(.*)(?=\))`. If it is the only string on a line, this will work.

Comment: It finds the whole text between. I need to find the specific `(` and `)`

Comment: Then, since JavaScript regex does not support recursion, you need to clarify if the parentheses can only be paired, and if they are, specify what nested depth you want to support, and if you want to support unlimited depth, you can't use regex, write your own parsing function.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what if I create 2 regex functions that will each replace just one specific character. One will be responsible for `(` and the other one for `)`?

Comment: Regarding *It finds the whole text between*: yes, but you can replace all `(` and `)` in the match with `string.replace`. See https://jsfiddle.net/1hfeoxzk/

Comment: But since it [does not work in the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70665929/regex-to-get-2-characters-between-other-2-characters-and-not-include-specific-te) please consider writing a specific parser for this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you elaborate on what specifically you recommend? Not really sure what do you mean by parsing

Comment: Check char by char until you find the starting boundary (you may also use a regex, too, for this), then use stack for `(` and `)` and omit all of them until you find   a paired one.

Answer (score 1):

As you already use a lookbehind in the pattern with JavaScript, you could use an infinite quantifier in the lookbehind, match the 2 parenthesis that you don't want to keep and capture in group 1 what you want to keep.

In the replacement use group 1 using `$1`

```
(?<=\[\]\([^()]*)\(([^()]*\))\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is:

  - `\[]` Match `[]`
  - `\([^()]*` Match `(` and 0+ times any char except `(` and `)`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\(` Match `(`
- `([^()]*\))` Capture **group 1**, match 0+ times any char except `(` and `)`
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/klkdz8/1)

```js
const s = "[](first-(second))"
const regex = /(?<=\[]\([^()]*)\(([^()]*\))\)/;
console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1"))
```

Or using 2 capture groups instead of a lookbehind:

```
(\[]\([^()]*)\(([^()]*\))\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZK2ac/1)

```js
const s = "[](first-(second))"
const regex = /(\[]\([^()]*)\(([^()]*\))\)/;
console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1$2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a stylish code, why not to go the easy way?
Extract the substring without external brackets, replace & concat. the removed chars

`s = '[](first-(second))'`

```
mySubstring = s.substring(3, s.length -2);  // 'first-(second)'
//your replacement func.
result = '[]('+mySubstring+')';             //'[](first-second)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example (not using lookaheads).  It should steer you in the correct direction.

Using 2 capture groups, and some non-greedy sets, you can assemble your target string.

It assumes no additional nested parenthesis or brackets, although you can modify to your needs to only include alphanumeric characters in the character sets.

```js
const d = '[](foo-(bar)) [](foo2-(bar2))'
const rx = /(\[\]\([^-\(\)\[\]]*?-)\(([^\)]*?)\)\)/g

const m = rx.exec(d)
console.log(m)

const fixed = d.replace(rx, '$1$2)')
console.log(fixed)
```